# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying return a uint64_t number

Tags: ios, objective-c, memcpy

I keep on getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I am trying to log the result of this function? What am I doing wrong?

```
-(uint64_t) rand64bitNum {
    uint32_t left = arc4random();
    uint32_t right = arc4random();
    uint64_t randNum = 0;
    memcpy(&randNum, &left, sizeof(left));
    uint16_t offset = sizeof(left);
    memcpy(&randNum+offset, &right, sizeof(right));
    return randNum;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&randnum+offset` doesn't do what you think it does; pointer addition is performed in units of the thing being pointed to.  So you probably want `(char *)&randnum + offset`.

Comment: +1 for explaining the OP's error.  I think he's going about this the wrong way, though.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation for your memory error is given in @OliCharlesworth's answer, but I wanted to present a better solution that doesn't require `memcpy` at all:

```
- (uint64_t)rand64bitNum
{
    uint64_t left = arc4random();
    uint64_t right = arc4random();
    uint64_t randNum = (right << 32) | left;
    return randNum;
}
```

Maybe even better, and leaving (almost) no room for error, you could use [`arc4random_buf(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_buf.3.html):

```
- (uint64_t)rand64bitNum
{
    uint64_t randNum;
    arc4random_buf(&randNum, sizeof randNum);
    return randNum;
}
```

Comment: Like `union { struct { uint32_t left; uint32_t right; }; uint64_t randNum; }`?  That would work too.  I think `arc4random_buf` is still better, though.